# Analytical Solution to 2nd Order Non Homogeneous Diff EQ

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the analytical solution to the following diff eq:

$af''+f'=1$ with the boundary conditions $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$

$a$ is a parameter

I haven't done much in solving non-homogeneous differential equations.  I looked up how to do it and am trying to do it using the method of coefficients.

I found the complementary solution, which I think is $$f_c=c_1e^{-t/a} + c_2e^0$$

I can't really figure out how to find the particular solution, since most of the examples I've found involve the solution being a function of some certain form and using that to find the particular solution.

Any help? I don't even know if I'm going in the right direction at this point or not.

Comment: this ODE can be easily handled with laplace transform.are you familier with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides of the ODE, we have
$$
as^2F(s) - asf(0) - af'(0) + sF(s) - f(0) = \frac1s.
$$
Solving for $F(s)$:
$$
F(s) = \frac{a s^2+a s f'(0)+s+1}{s^2 (a s+1)}.
$$
Partial fraction decomposition yields
$$
F(s) = \frac 1{s^2} + \frac{1-a}s + \frac{a^2}{1+as} +\frac{af'(0)}s - \frac{a^2f'(0)}{1+as}.
$$
Inverting the Laplace transform, we have
$$
f(t) = -a f'(0) e^{-\frac{t}{a}}+a e^{-\frac{t}{a}}+a f'(0)-a+t+1.
$$
From the initial condition $f(1)=0$, we find that
$$
f'(0) = \frac{2 e^{1/a}}{a-a e^{1/a}}+1.
$$
It follows that
$$
f(t) =\frac{e^{1/a} \left(-2 e^{-\frac{t}{a}}-t+1\right)+t+1}{1-e^{1/a}}.
$$

Comment: Using Laplace transform was definitely the way to go here.  I haven't done a Laplace transform in 2+ years so I just forgot they existed.  Thanks for the help man.

Comment: @Western Glad I could help.

Comment: After taking the Laplace transform in the first step, I ended up with: $as^2 F(s) - asf(0) - af'(0) + sF(s) - f(0) = 1/s$.  This simplified to $as^2F(s)-as+sF(s)-1=1/s$ which isn't exactly what you got.  It seems like my $asf(0)-af'(0)$ term is different than what you got and I just took that off of a Laplace table?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, it should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

$$af''+f'=1$$
$$af''+f'-1=0$$
$$a(f-t)''+(f-t)'=0$$
Now it's homogeneous
$$ag''+g'=0$$
Where $g=(f-t)$
For $a\ne 0$:
$$ar^2+r=0 \implies r(ar+1)=0 \implies S_r=\{0,-\dfrac 1 a\}$$
Therefore the solution is: 
$$g(t)=c_1+c_2e^{-t/a}$$
$$\boxed {f(t)=c_1+c_2e^{-t/a}+t}$$
Apply initial conditions to find the constants $c_1,c_2$

For $a=0$ we have :
$$f'=1 \implies f(t)=t+c$$
The initial conditions are not compatible.